# jQuery .text() method returns empty string

Tags: jquery, momentjs

HTML code:

```
<div class="m-t-md">
    <small class="pull-left">
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
        <span id="updatedTime_SalesTab"></span>
    </small>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function updatedDate() {
        var testDateUtc = moment.utc();
        var local = moment(testDateUtc).local(); 

        var updatedTime = moment(local).format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A");
        console.log('updated: ', updatedTime); // log: "updated:  12/20/2016 11:44 AM"

        $('#updatedTime_SalesTab').text(updatedTime);
    }

    updatedDate();
});
```

But I have only clock icon, span is empty. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: code looks fine for me.. did you check your console window for errors?

Comment: Here is jsfiddle and works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/FLhpq/7410/

Comment: Did you forgot to include plugins ?

Comment: yes, i checked. no errors or warnings.

Comment: Maybe you have other CSS that's hiding the span?

Comment: Please provide your full code.

Comment: Do you see the time if you look in the Elements tab?

Comment: if Barmar is right then @DenysM what you can try is `$('#updatedTime_SalesTab').text(updatedTime).show();`

Comment: @Barmar, css rule: display: inline. i tried `$('#updatedTime_SalesTab').text(updatedTime).show();` but still have empty span

Comment: Are you using something like Twitter Bootstrap? Maybe it's doing something that affects the display.

Comment: Something else on your site is causing the problem. There's no way we can tell from what you've posted.

Comment: i replaced function  `updatedDate()` outside `$(document).ready(function () {}` and it solved my problem. thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace text with Html

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    function updatedDate() {
        var testDateUtc = moment.utc();
        var local = moment(testDateUtc).local(); 

        var updatedTime = moment(local).format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A");
        console.log('updated: ', updatedTime); // log: "updated:  12/20/2016 11:44 AM"

        $('#updatedTime_SalesTab').html(updatedTime);
    }

    updatedDate();
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! i tried but it's not working (but should).

Answer (score 0):

try this, this works fine for me

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
function updatedDate() {
        var testDateUtc = moment.utc();
        var local = moment(testDateUtc).local(); 

        var updatedTime = moment(local).format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A");
        console.log('updated: ', updatedTime); // log: "updated:  12/20/2016 11:44 AM"

        $('#updatedTime_SalesTab').text(updatedTime);
    }
    updatedDate();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>


function updatedDate() {
    var testDateUtc = moment.utc();
    var local = moment(testDateUtc).local(); 

    var updatedTime = moment(local).format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A");
    console.log('updated: ', updatedTime); // log: "updated:  12/20/2016 11:44 AM"

    $('#updatedTime_SalesTab').text(updatedTime);
   updatedDate();
}
</script>
<div class="m-t-md">
    <small class="pull-left">
        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
        <span id="updatedTime_SalesTab"></span>
    </small>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case this solved my problem:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    updatedDate();
});

function updatedDate() {
    var testDateUtc = moment.utc();
    var local = moment(testDateUtc).local(); 

    var updatedTime = moment(local).format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A");
    console.log('updated: ', updatedTime); // log: "updated:  12/20/2016 11:44 AM"

    $('#updatedTime_SalesTab').text(updatedTime);
}
```